# Escape & in Java

Tags: java

I have this very basic SOAPElement.

The problem is that my password is `test18T&T`. 
I need a way to make the password with `&amp;` like `test18T&amp;T`

How can I do this? Is this already implemented behind the scenes?

Thanks

```
SOAPElement ticketUpdate = body.addChildElement("TicketUpdate", "con");

ticketUpdate.addChildElement("UserLogin", "con").addTextNode(user);
ticketUpdate.addChildElement("Password", "con").addTextNode(password);
```

Comment: if the `&` in the password is preset fixed then it seems to me as a simple regex issue

Comment: the password comes from a properties file

Comment: password.replaceAll("&","&amp;")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight forward way I can think of is using the replace all function of th String API

```
ticketUpdate.addChildElement("Password", "con").addTextNode(password.replaceAll("&", "&amp;");
```

Comment: Won't this also replace `&amp;` with `&amp;amp;` ?

Comment: @ryvantage this will replace `&amp;` with `&amp;amp;`  Actually

Comment: you could prevent that by first replacing al &amp with & but that feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is something like this. Taking in mind that the `&` will always be there and we can use that as reference you can use the following.

`input: test18T&T`

`output: test18T&amp;T`

```
SOAPElement ticketUpdate = body.addChildElement("TicketUpdate", "con");
ticketUpdate.addChildElement("UserLogin", "con").addTextNode(user);
String[] parts = password.split("&");
parts[0] = parts[0]+"&amp;";
String newPassword = "";
for(String part : parts){
  newPassword = newPassword+part;
}
ticketUpdate.addChildElement("Password", "con").addTextNode(newPassword );
```